# How to select items that do not show up in a second list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists and I want to select items that are not in the second list from the first list. I have no Linq experience to I think this should be a good way to start learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Except for this:

```
var query = list1.Except(list2);
```